# Como saber a ordem de execução dos métodos dos componentes em JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Como descubro qual a ordem de execução de métodos em [jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf)? Minha dúvida é baseada no seguinte, certa vez um botão estava disparando atrasado um método, pois não havia escolhido de forma correta a o método do botão.

Neste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370309/execute-pcommandlink-action-before-onclick-event) o cara responde a sequência de execução.

Comment: Não está muito clara a pergunta. A resposta é o que está no link?

Comment: Isso tem muito mais a ver com os callbacks do JavaScript / requests http e AJAX do que com o ciclo de vida do JSF. A API de cada componenete (e.g., [commandLink](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/commandLink.html)) indica qual atributo da tag corresponde a cada tipo de evento. Pense como se não houvesse JSF no meio (`onclick` é processado no cliente antes da requisição, então a requisição ajax acontece - `action` - você atualiza o DOM - `update` - e pode fazer mais alguma coisa - `oncomplete`).

Comment: Certo mas existe alguma forma, site, manual ou algo do tipo para me informar isso?

Comment: @bfavaretto sim, a resposta do link é a minha duvida, mas a pergunta do link não é minha, é mais uma curiosidade. Porque as vezes em um projeto usando `JSF` com `Primefaces`, me deparo com situação do tipo, um botão vai ser bloqueado ou não se a `datatable` esta preenchida....

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly eu vi o `javadoc`, interessante, as informações que contem descrevendo em qual lado ocorre os métodos. Mas maiores informações aonde encontro? Por exemplo vc disse que o `action` atualiza o DOM...

Comment: Na verdade o `update` o faz (veja resposta do utluiz). Que seja do meu conhecimento não existe um manual integrado detalhando isso (talvez algum livro ou curso do PrimeFaces). Acho que isso ocorre pela documentação assumir certa familiaridade com JSF AJAX e Javascript (na teoria a sequencia deveria ser intuitiva). Porém de uma olhada no [User Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation). Principalmente nas tags `AjaxBehavior`, `AutoComplete` e `CommandButton`, bem como no Capítulo 4 - *Partial Rendering and Processing* e 6 - *JavaScript API*. Todos os componentes acabam sendo parecidos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem, você quer entender melhor a sequência de eventos entre a camada de apresentação (Javascript) e os controllers (managed beans).

[Este post](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=830) do blog do Prime Faces explica o funcionamento dos eventos de *callback* Ajax `oncomplete`, `onsuccess` e `onstart`.

A ordem geral seria a seguinte:

- `onstart`: evento de início da requisição que executa um javascript.
- `actionListener`: atualiza propriedades no *manabed bean*.
- `action`: executa ação especificada do *manabed bean*.
- `onsuccess` / `onerror`: eventos javascript executado se houve sucesso ou erro na ação, respectivamente.
- `update`: atualiza componentes do DOM para refletir as ações realizadas via javascript, mas pode chamar métodos usados pelos componentes atualizados via *postback*.
- `oncomplete`: evento javascript executado depois que tudo foi concluído, com erro ou não

## Sobre `action` e `actionListener`

Um `action` é a ação onde as regras de negócio efetivamente irão executar, culminando geralmente numa navegação. O método de `action` geralmente retorna uma String.

O `actionListener` é como um evento que ocorre antes do `action` a fim de atualizar valores, realizar alguma validação, log, etc. Você pode ainda cancelar a o `action` se necessário. Num `actionLisener`, você pode acessar os valores enviados pelo usuário através do parâmetro `ActionEvent` **antes** que o JSF atualize as propriedades do `ManagedBean`.

Já vi alguns desenvolvedores erroneamente acessarem propriedades do `ManagedBean` no evento `actionListener` e gravá-las no banco de dados. Só depois eles percebem que os valores ficam defasados.