# Como carregar uma função jQuery ao carregar uma página que usa JSF e Primefaces

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

Estou usando uma função para verificar se todos o checkbox estão marcados a realizar o load de um cadastrado já preenchido.

Então queria saber como chamar a função.

```
function selectAllCheckbox() {

  var booleanArray = new Array();
  var allCheckBox = $('input[id*="ufs"]');

  $(allCheckBox).each(function() {
      if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
          booleanArray.push($(this).prop('checked'));                 
      }
  });

  if (booleanArray.length == 27) {
      allCheckBox.last().prop('checked', true);
  }
}
```

Neste eu verifico se todos os checkbox estão preenchidos, caso sim, marco o checkbox todos.

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="ufs" value="#{lojaBean.pojo.ufsInss}" layout="grid" columns="4" styleClass="columnLeft">
    <f:selectItems value="#{lojaBean.helper.estados}"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Todos" itemValue=""/>
    <p:ajax event="change" onstart="selectAll(event)" update="ufs"/> 
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Eu uso outro método `selectAll(event)` para ao selecionar o botão, selecionar todos. Gostaria de quando carregar uma página, ela verifica se todos checkbox foram preenchidos, mas não sei como chamar...

Answer (score 1):

Consegui efetuar o que necessitava utilizando a possibilidade que o sistema me oferece.

Quando eu faço isso `<f:selectItem itemLabel="Todos" itemValue=""/>` eu repasso a lista uma `String` vazia quando seleciono este `checkbox`.

Antes de salvar eu trato para não gravar no banco esta `String` vazia.

```
private void removeNullValueFromArray(Pojo pojo) {

    List<String> listUf = pojo.getUfsInss();
    listUf.removeAll(Collections.singleton(""));

    pojo.setUfsInss(listUf);
}
```

Ao carrgar a página usando a tag,

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{lojaBean.load}" type="preRenderView"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Eu chamo no `Bean` o metodo `load` aonde verifico se a lista esta preenchida com a quantidade considerada cheia, e ai passo para o `List` adicionar uma `String` vazia.

```
if (isTodosEstadosSelecionados()) {
    this.getPojo().getUfsInss().add("");                
}
```

E ai, funciona!

Answer (score 0):

Adicione um script ao arquivo usando a tag [`<h:outputScript>`](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-include-javascript-file-in-jsf/) e adicione normalmente um *listener* do tipo `load` do jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
     selectAllCheckbox();
})
```

Outra alternativa é apenas inserir o código Javascript *inline* usando uma tag `<script>` no seu facelet. Veja alguns exemplos [aqui](http://balusc.blogspot.de/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html).

No entanto, isso vai funcionar se a página inteira for carregada. Se for apenas uma atualização parcial com AJAX, use o atributo `oncomplete` para executar algo após a atualização do DOM. Considere a [ordem dos eventos do PrimeFaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8452/227).

Comment: Cara, fiquei em dúvida porque é o seguinte, vamos supor que eu use o oncomplete, tem como eu marcar um checkbox usando a minha função usando este evento?

Comment: @Macario1983 Tem sim. A sua checkbox tem que ter o atributo `widgetvar` com algum nome. Então você pode fazer referência ao campo através do Javascript por esse nome e usar a função `check()` da API *Client Side*. Veja o User Guide do PrimeFaces para maiores detalhes, pois lá você tem a lista de funções *client* de cada componente.

Comment: Porque é o seguinte, eu uso a página dentro de outra...Tem uma página principal que contem os blocos das outras, como o topo, meio e parte mais baixa. Ai nessa página eu já chamo o `outputScript`. E ai as páginas implementadas entram no meio...Entende?

Comment: @Macario1983 Não é melhor fazer essa lógica no método do seu `ManagedBean`? Ao carregar a lista no método `getEstados()`, aplique o código que define `true` no último elemento caso os 27 estejam preenchidos.

Comment: Cara, eu tentei isso já antes, mas como fazer com o `checkbox` do `selectItem` esteja marcado, mas não deu certo, você tem ideia como faz?