# Chamando função JQUERY com Primefaces

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, primefaces

Quero executar uma chamada JQuery após o clique de um botão:

```
<p:commandButton id="btnSelecionaLote" icon="ui-icon-pencil" action="#{loteController.selecionarLote()}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{lote.id}" target="#{loteController.loteBean.id}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
</p:commandButton>
```

**JQuery**

```
function testePrime(){
        $("#formLote\\:btnSelecionaLote").click(function() {
            alert("testing!");
        });
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como carregar uma função jQuery ao carregar uma página que usa JSF e Primefaces](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11128/como-carregar-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-jquery-ao-carregar-uma-p%c3%a1gina-que-usa-jsf-e-primefaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema com o seguinte código:

```
onclick="jQuery(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('tabelaRaca')).hide()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que importar o seu **arquivo.js** que tem a função que quer chamar para isso basta incluir o `outputScript` no seu codigo:

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="arquivo.js" />
```

**RESPOSTA NO STACK:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771496/perform-onclick-on-radiobutton-in-primefaces

Comment: não funcionou :|

Comment: Você está colocando esse codigo no HTML dentro desse escopo: $(document).ready(function(){....})

Comment: estou sim não funciona :|

Comment: não sei se percebeu mas vc tá usando html nativo eu estou usando primefaces

Comment: se liga ele tá gerando isso quando inspeciono elemento id = j_idt7:formLote:j_idt46:0:btnSelecionaLote

Comment: Resolvi com isso aqui onclick="jQuery(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('tabelaRaca')).hide()"

Comment: Poste a resposta pra gente fechar a pergunta